# Why does boost's managed_mapped_file :: shrink_to_fit behave differently on Windows and Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, boost

This is about C ++ library boost.

The `managed_mapped_file :: shrink_to_fit` function works differently on Linux and Windows.

On Linux, this function succeeds even if the target instance exists.
However, on Windows, this function will fail if the target instance exists.

Is this correct behavior?

It seems correct to do the same behavior, is this a bug?

I put the sample code below.

Compilation environment

- boost:version.1.65.1
- Windows

  - VisualStudio2017
  - WSL(Ubuntu16.04)
- Linux

  - UbuntuServer17.10,
  - Clang++5.0,
  - g++7.2.0

Compile with

clang++-5.0 -std=c++1z ./test.cpp -o test -lpthread

```
#define BOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/file_mapping.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
using intAlloc = bip::allocator<int, bip::managed_mapped_file::segment_manager>;
using intVec = std::vector<int, intAlloc>;

int main() {
    bip::managed_mapped_file *p_file_vec;
    intVec *vecObj;

    std::string fileName = "tmp.dat";
    size_t fileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1;
    bip::file_mapping::remove(fileName.c_str());

    p_file_vec = new bip::managed_mapped_file(bip::create_only, fileName.c_str(), fileSize);
    vecObj = p_file_vec->construct<intVec>("myVecName")(p_file_vec->get_allocator<int>());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        vecObj->push_back(1 + 100);
    }
    p_file_vec->flush();

    try
    {   //Fail when execute on Windows(WSL),but Success on Linux(Ubuntu17.10).
        std::cout << "try to shrink:pointer has existed yet!" << std::endl;
        bip::managed_mapped_file::shrink_to_fit(fileName.c_str());
        std::cout << "success to shrink!" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception  &ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "fail to shrink!" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;;
    }
    std::cout <<"please pless enter key."<< std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    try
    {   //Success when execute on Windows(WSL) and Linux(Ubuntu17.10).
        delete p_file_vec;
        std::cout << "try to shrink:pointer has deleted!" << std::endl;
        bip::managed_mapped_file::shrink_to_fit(fileName.c_str());
        std::cout << "success to shrink!" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "fail to shrink!" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;;
    }
    std::cout << "please pless enter key." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `new` and `delete` in C++ (rule of thumb).

Apart from that

```
    delete p_file_vec;
```

does NOT delete anything physical. It effectively disconnects from the mapped file. This is also why `shrink_to_fit` works: [the documentation explicitly says](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_memory_segment_advanced_features.growing_managed_memory):

> If the application can find a moment where no process is attached it can grow or shrink to fit the managed segment.

And [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost/interprocess/basic_managed__idp65525280.html#idp65563168-bb)

> [image]

So, in short: the behaviour is correct on both platforms. It's just UNDEFINED what happens in your case when you shrink while the mapped file is in use (on Ubuntu).

### Fixed Code:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72e5c92e15d2280e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
using intAlloc = bip::allocator<int, bip::managed_mapped_file::segment_manager>;
using intVec = std::vector<int, intAlloc>;

int main() {
    std::string const fileName = "tmp.dat";
    bip::file_mapping::remove(fileName.c_str());

    {
        bip::managed_mapped_file file_vec(bip::create_only, fileName.c_str(), 1l << 20);
        auto *vecObj = file_vec.construct<intVec>("myVecName")(file_vec.get_allocator<int>());

        for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            vecObj->push_back(1 + 100);
        }
    }

    try { // Success when execute on Windows(WSL) and Linux(Ubuntu17.10).
        std::cout << "try to shrink:pointer has deleted!" << std::endl;
        bip::managed_mapped_file::shrink_to_fit(fileName.c_str());
        std::cout << "success to shrink!" << std::endl;
    } catch (const std::exception &ex) {
        std::cerr << "fail to shrink!" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer solved the problem.
But what if I need to assign variables dynamically?